# Perfmon can't create data collector set on Windows 7 x64

Tags: perfmon, performancecounter

I'm trying to create a data collector set using Perfmon. When I right click 'New -> Data Collector Set' in the User Defined folder, I see the wizard dialog appear. However, the 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled. All I can do is click on Cancel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this while googling a problem with the disk defragger. The recommendation I found was to (backup first!) remove the registry key:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\RPC\Internet

I exported the key for a backup; deleted the key; then rebooted. After reboot I could run the disk defragger and also add my own data collector sets in Perfmon.

For some reason the task scheduler couldn't start, which prevented both the disk defragger and Perfmon from running. They can each schedule tasks, and didn't run with full capabilities without the task scheduler interface available (the disk defragger didn't run at all). Deleting that key allowed the task schedule to start properly.  I haven't seen any side affects...yet!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have the registry HKLM\Software\Microsoft\RPC\Internet. Still don't know have to deal with the problem.