# Perfmon won't create a new data collector set based on custom template (Win7 & WinServer 2008)

Tags: perfmon, performancecounter

I am trying to create a new data collector set based upon an XML template file I have already created (from PAL). I was able to do it before. Then, I wanted to automate it using logman with "logman import PAL -xml "C:\sqlserver.xml"" This didn't work, saying "The parameter is incorrect". I was fine with it not working, until I found that I could no longer create it through perfmon.

The problem is exactly how it is described here: [Perfmon can't create data collector set on Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939404/perfmon-cant-create-data-collector-set-on-windows-7-x64) . I right click 'New -> Data Collector Set' in the User Defined folder, I see the wizard dialog appear. Once I browse and select my xml file, the 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled, the list view becomes empty (those 3 defaults disappear), and the only things I can do are hit the browse button again and choose a different file or cancel. However, unlike the guy I linked to, that registry key doesn't exist on any machine this is happening on.

I did this on my Windows 7 machine as well as two VMs with Windows Server 2008 SP2

Comment: So, just to clarify, you only get this is on X64, and works fine in other OS that are x86? Was your successful 2008 attempt x86 or 64?

Comment: I got it to work on Windows 7 (64) and the 2008 (x86) machines. After trying logman, all three are having this problem.